# Choose element Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, viewstate, ionic-framework

I have problem using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) with Angular JS. I get list using Ajax but I don't know how send it.

```
 <li ng-repeat=" list in list">
        <a class="item item-icon-right " ng-click='next({list})'>
            <i class='icon ion-chevron-right'></i>
            <p>{{list.rejestracja}}, {{list.auto}}</p>
            <p>{{list.klient}}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I would like to get another view only those elements that I chose from this list.

Ok sorry. When you choose one item from the list, I would like to show it in the next view. May show more:

And in my controller I have the following function:

```
$scope.next = function(message) {
    $scope.user = message;
    console.log($scope.user);
    $state.go('master');
}
```

So when I go to 'master' view I can't use this `$scope.user`, it doesn't show me it in view. Does someone know how change it?

Comment: Please clarify a little bit your question. to where do you want to send the list? Where are your controller?

Comment: I wrote something more. I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ionic uses ui-router so if your next view is a nested view you should be able to use your controllers variables in a child controller through scope inheritance (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views).
if your view is not nested, then you have some options

```
1-put it in $rootScope
2-use session/local storage
3-create a service to hold that information across the application
```

the way to do it depends on the additional functionality and livetime of the information
if passing that data, is all there is ever going to happen you could use $rootScope
or creating a clipboard service that holds all those peaces of random data

using $rootScope in your controllers inject $rootScope in both the one with the data source and the one owning the view you want to display the data on.
then in your source controllers next function

```
$scope.next = function(message) {
  $scope.user = message;
  $rootScope.user=message;
  console.log($scope.user);
  $state.go('master');
}
```

then in your destination controller do

```
$scope.message=$rootScope.message;
```

that should give you access to the message in your view.

this is not the cleanest way, but it will allow you to bypass this problem and not get you frustrated, you can revisit this an implement a better solution when you fell like it

Comment: Could you give any example ? I'm using ui-router. I think it can be problem about reload view. In console.log($scope.user)  it show me it what i want but in view not.

Comment: is your next view a nested view?

Comment: I'm not sure so i show you.$stateProvider
  .state('master', {
    url: '/master',
    templateUrl: 'templates/master.html',
    controller: 'MyController'
  })

Comment: no is not. i am taking you are fairly new to angular so i am updating my answer with a code snip using $rootScope

Comment: Could You explain what is destination controller ?

Comment: the controller that manages the view where you want to display your information

Comment: np, if you have any more doubts leave a comment

Comment: Hey, I have some questions, I tried do it, but I don't know why I can't. I copy this code and wrote this $scope.message=$rootScope.message; but in apps are some problems. Can  may be a problem that the same views have the same controller ?? If you need more infromation I'll send you code

Comment: on your next you where assigning $rootScope.user=message.
so $rootScope.message doesn't exist, but $rootScope.user does

Comment: So this 2 views can be in one controller ?

Comment: not sure what you are asking? whats your native language?

Comment: yes thats the idea of the separation, you can have as many views as you want for the same controller

Comment: When I input '$scope.message=$rootScope.message;' or something similar i've problem. '<li ng-repeat=" list in list">
        <a class="item item-icon-right " ng-click='next({list})'>
            <i class='icon ion-chevron-right'></i>
            <p>{{list.rejestracja}}, {{list.auto}}</p>
            <p>{{list.klient}}</p>
        </a>
    </li>' It don't show me list. And any other function does't works.

Comment: thats very vague, fid out the error on your cconsole